# .gitignore in subdirectory is getting ignored

Tags: gitignore

I have created a .gitignore file in a subdirectory.

```
/errors/company/.gitignore
```

I need it to ignore the file `/errors/company/seiten/start/content.phtml`.

Content of .gitignore:

```
seiten/start/content.phtml
```

But it does still show the file if execute `git status`. Why?

Comment: Have you already commited the `.gitignore` file? Why don't you have just one `.gitignore` file in the root directory of your project instead of having it in a subdirectory, is there any special reason for doing that ?

Comment: @dglozano, I commited the .gitignore file and it is still not working.

Comment: It is also ignored if I add `/errors/company/seiten/start/content.phtml` to the main .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

If you have already commited the `.gitignore` file, and you still see that file in `git status`, it is because the file was being tracked from before. You should do the following:

```
git rm --cached /errors/company/seiten/start/content.phtml
```

That should do the trick.

PD: I would leave just one `.gitignore` in the root directory with all the ignored paths and files.

Comment: It works! I found this info:
"A gitignore file specifies intentionally **untracked files** that git should ignore. Note that all the gitignore files really concern only files that are not already tracked by git"

Comment: Ah damn, I have to revert my accept. It does still not work, it was only working because I had the entry in the main .gitignore.

Comment: @Black please, post the content of the root `.gitignore` and also the content of the one inside the subdirectory. Then run the following command and also upload its output to your quesiton `git check-ignore -v -- /errors/company/seiten/start/content.phtml`